# Understanding tangential acceleration

Tags: vectors

I'm self studying Feynman's Lectures on Physics, and he has a chapter devoted to vectors. At one point he discusses acceleration along a curve, and mentions that the change in velocity can be broken down into two components, one being tangential to the path.

> It is interesting to note that we can compose the velocity difference out of two parts; we can think of acceleration as having two components, Δv∥, in the direction tangent to the path and Δv⊥ at right angles to the path, as indicated in Fig. 11–8. The acceleration tangent to the path is, of course, **just the change in the length of the vector**, i.e., the change in the speed v:
>   a∥=dv/dt.(11.15)

The diagram shown (with colored additions by me) is: [image: vector diagram]

I expect the change in velocity (difference in length) to be the part of the arrow highlighted in blue, not the entire portion that is to the right of the vector $Δv_⊥$. What is wrong with my intuition?

(This can be moved to physics exchange if it's more appropriate there, but I felt that I'm just missing something about the mathematical model).

Comment: Velocity is a vector so a change in velocity can be a change in direction as well as a change in length.

Comment: @JohnDouma True, but the the discussion here is specifically tangential change which is just the change in magnitude.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JohnDouma - please read the second to last paragraph (I expect...) - the difference in length should be as shown by the blue arrow. The original diagram does not show the blue. It implies that the little bit of black before it is also part of the tangential acceleration. I seem to be missing something.

Comment: If you want help you should ask clear questions. Your title says "Understanding tangential acceleration". If $v_1$ is your original velocity then the tangential change is along $v_1$, not $v_2$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Sorry, I'm not sure how to improve the question. It boils down to an (apparent) inconsistency - the text quote says to compare the length of the vectors. The diagram given does something else. I must be misinterpreting something, but don't understand enough to express it better.

Comment: If you make that red line a circular arc instead of a straight line segment, it should become obvious that the black part of $\mathbf v_2$ has the same length as $\mathbf v_1$.

Comment: @amd - that's exactly the point of confusion. If so, why shouldn't the tangential vector be the blue arrow only (as opposed to the diagram in the original)?

Comment: @amd (To be clear, the red line is entirely my own addition).